# Android Studio - implementation material-calendarview can't resolve. Old versions work

Tags: android, gradle

Can anyone help with this issue? Not sure why its not resolving for 2.0.1 but it is for 1.4.3

Failed to resolve: com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1
Affected Modules: app

build.grade (Project) file has:

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

build.gradle(Module) file has:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1' <-"correct" per docs
  // implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3' <-- works
  // implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1' <-- does not work
  // implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1' <-- does not work
  // implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3' <-- does not work
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

Also tried adding via the Project Structure but it cannot find com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview if I search for it but if I search material-calendarview i can find 1.4.3

Thanks

[Project Structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFoI5.png)

[Project Structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvsSo.png)

Comment: Make sure you added the `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in root build.gradle it should be inside `allProjects` 

```allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}```

Comment: 1.4.3 is available in maven central but 2.0.1 is not https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: ok Looks like you added in buildScript,  you should move that to allProjects

Comment: Sorry - very new to Android Development so I am having trouble understanding jitpack vs maven.  https://jitpack.io/#prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/2.0.1

Comment: There are different online repositories where developers upload and host their libraries. You need to specify the repository so your build tools know from where to download the library.

Comment: Maven central repository is repository provided by Maven community. It contains a large number of commonly used libraries.  Similarly JitPack is a public maven repository and serves artifacts.
So I just pointed out 1.4.3 is available in maven central and 2.0.1 is only available in Jitpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a new project, it's possible you have settings.gradle, then you should add it there:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

You can always remove this code block from the settings.gradle and use it as suggested in the github repo. Make sure  that you add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` inside `allprojects`, not just the `repositories` block. Like this:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked (adding to settings.gradle).

Comment: @milhouse19 I'm glad it worked. Can you please mark it as an accepted answer. :)